# MPAndroidChart Display Label Over Horizontal Line on Graph

Tags: java, android, graph, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to display custom text centered between 2 points on the graph?

I've got MPAndroidChart setup to display a step function type graph (representing hours spent doing a specific task) with horizontal and vertical lines only. What I would like to be able to do is show a label over the horizontal sections indicating the size of the section (aka the time spent calculated by taking the difference between the x values). Is there a way to do this? I've been look into modifying the library but I can't seem to figure out where would be the correct place to do so.

My best guess would be some changes in BarLineChartBase `onDraw()` method or maybe in the LineChartRenderer `drawLinear()` method.

Here is what I am able to produce:

[image: current graph]

Here is an example of what I am trying to produce:

[image: example graph]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Just add a new method drawTime() to the LineChart class at the end of onDraw() right after drawDescription(). Since each horizontal line is described by 2 Entry points I simply loop through 2 entries at a time for my single data set and calculate the difference:

```
protected void drawTime(Canvas c)
{
    Paint timePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    timePaint.setTextSize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(16));
    timePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    timePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    MPPointD position;

    LineData data = this.getLineData();
    ILineDataSet dataSet = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < dataSet.getEntryCount(); i+=2)
    {
        Entry e1 = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(i-1);
        Entry e2 = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(i);

        float time = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        position = getPixelForValues(e1.getX() + time/2, e1.getY() - 0.05f, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        c.drawText(String.valueOf(time), (float)position.x, (float)position.y, timePaint);
    }
}
```

The resulting graph [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Vg2.png)

Comment: I'm using mpandroidchart in my project but am unable to edit the LineChart class. Even so, in the LineChart class I'm not seeing an onDraw() or drawDescription() method. Could you in more detail explain where you implemented this change?